# dagger2 does not provide injection in base activity

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I am trying to implement the latest version of Dagger2 in a Single-Activity app, but it is not known why, when initializing my starting activity, Dagger2 does not inject dependencies, I has a
fatal error in my base activity : **Unable to resume activity kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property navigatorHolder has not been initialized**

here is my code

**AppComponent:**

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [
AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class,
ActivityInjectionModule::class,
ActivityProviderModule::class,
AndroidInjectionModule::class,
NetworkModule::class,
RemoteModule::class,
NavigationModule::class,
ParserModule::class,
CacheModule::class])

interface AppComponent : AndroidInjector<App> {

@Component.Builder
interface Builder {
    @BindsInstance
    fun application(application: Application): Builder
    @BindsInstance
    fun context(context: Context) : Builder
    fun build(): AppComponent
}

override fun inject(app: App)
```

}

**App:**

```
class App : DaggerApplication(){
private val applicationInjector = 
DaggerAppComponent.builder().application(this).context(this).build()
override fun applicationInjector(): AndroidInjector<out DaggerApplication>  = 
applicationInjector


companion object {
    lateinit var cicerone: Cicerone<Router>
        private set
}
override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    cicerone = Cicerone.create()
    initAppComponent()
    initStetho()
    Timber.plant(Timber.DebugTree())
}
```

**AppActivity:**

```
class AppActivity : MvpAppCompatActivity() , HasAndroidInjector, RouterProvider {

@Inject
lateinit var dispatchingAndroidInjector: DispatchingAndroidInjector<Any>

@Inject
lateinit var mainActivityProvider: ActivityProvider


@Inject
lateinit var navigatorHolder: Lazy<NavigatorHolder>

@Inject
override lateinit var ciceroneRouter: Router

override fun androidInjector(): AndroidInjector<Any>  = dispatchingAndroidInjector

private val navigator : Navigator by lazy {
    CustomSupportAppNavigator(this, supportFragmentManager, R.layout.activity_main)
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, persistentState: PersistableBundle?) {
    AndroidInjection.inject(this)
    mainActivityProvider.acitvity = this

    Timber.e("onCreate AppActivity")
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    initBottomBar()
}
override fun onResumeFragments() {
    super.onResumeFragments()
    navigatorHolder.get().setNavigator(navigator)
}
```

**ActivityInjectionModule**

```
@Module(includes = [AndroidInjectionModule::class])
interface ActivityInjectionModule {

@ContributesAndroidInjector(
    modules = [FragmentInjectionModule::class]
)
fun activityInjector() : AppActivity
}
```

**NavigationModule**

```
@Module
class NavigationModule {

@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideRouter() = App.cicerone.router

@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideNavigatorHolder() : NavigatorHolder {
    return App.cicerone.navigatorHolder
}

@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideLocalNavigationHolder(): LocalCiceroneHolder {
    return LocalCiceroneHolder()
}
}
```

Also i post android:name=".App" inandroid manifest.

I have tried many different options already, but I still cannot find the reason

Answer (score 0):

Can you change your App to like this and try again:

```
class App : DaggerApplication(){

private val appComponent = 
DaggerAppComponent.builder().application(this).context(this).build().inject(this)

companion object {
    lateinit var cicerone: Cicerone<Router>
        private set
}
override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    cicerone = Cicerone.create()
    initAppComponent()
    initStetho()
    Timber.plant(Timber.DebugTree())
}
```

Also remove `AndroidInjector<App>` from AppComponent

Comment: it didn't help(